# How can we find a control from a dynamically created table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data

The way i proceded is as follows:

table name :tbltt

1.I added a table from sourcecode

2.Created rows and coloumns in cs page

3.Data will get bind at runtime

4.I wanna save the tablevalus,For this wanna  find control inside it(there is dropdown  in each row and colomn)

Table s Below

```
public void createdynamictable()
    {
        string[] p = { "flag", "campusid", "ttid" };
        string[] v = { "3", campusID.ToString(), ddlTimetable.SelectedValue };
        DataTable dtt2 = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", p, v);
        if (dtt2.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dtTimeTable = new DataTable();
            dTable1 = new DataTable();

            ArrayList freeHours = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList PeriodCount = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList PeriodCount1 = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList PeriodDate = new ArrayList();
            int period = 0;
            period = dtt2.Rows.Count;
            HtmlTableRow tableRowhead = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell tableCellhead = new HtmlTableCell();
            // tableCellhead.ColSpan = period + 2;

            Label lblHead = new Label();
            lblHead.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            tableCellhead.Controls.Add(lblHead);

            tableRowhead.Controls.Add(tableCellhead);
            tbltt.Controls.Add(tableRowhead);
            HtmlTableRow tableRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            tableRow.BgColor = "#0272A8";
            tableRow.Height = "32";
            HtmlTableCell tableCell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            tableCell1.Width = "75px";
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = " Date";
            lbl.Font.Size = 12;
            lbl.Font.Bold = true;
            lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            tableCell1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            tableRow.Controls.Add(tableCell1);
            dtTimeTable.Columns.Add();
            dtTimeTable.Rows.Add();

            for (int k = 0; k <= dtt2.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                HtmlTableCell tableCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                Label lblPeriodHead = new Label();
                if (k < dtt2.Rows.Count)
                    lblPeriodHead.Text = dtt2.Rows[k][0].ToString();
                lblPeriodHead.Font.Size = 12;
                tableCell.Width = "85px";
                lblPeriodHead.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                lblPeriodHead.Font.Bold = true;
                tableCell.Controls.Add(lblPeriodHead);
                tableRow.Controls.Add(tableCell);
                dtTimeTable.Columns.Add();
                dtTimeTable.Rows[0][k] = lblPeriodHead.Text;

            }
            //done
            string[] p2 = { "flag", "campusid", "ttid" };
            string[] v2 = { "2", campusID.ToString(), ddlTimetable.SelectedValue };
            dt = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", p2, v2);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                tbltt.Controls.Add(tableRow);
                for (int m = 0; m < dt.Rows.Count; m++)
                {
                    HtmlTableRow tableRowday = new HtmlTableRow();
                    HtmlTableCell tableCellday = new HtmlTableCell();

                    //----------------------------------
                    HtmlTableCell tableCelldate = new HtmlTableCell();
                    Label lbldate = new Label();
                    lbldate.Text = dt.Rows[m][0].ToString();
                    lbldate.Font.Size = 9;
                    lbldate.Height = Unit.Pixel(20);
                    tableCelldate.Width = "85px";
                    lbldate.Height = Unit.Pixel(20);
                    tableCelldate.Controls.Add(lbldate);
                    dtTimeTable.Rows.Add();
                    dtTimeTable.Rows[m + 1][0] = lbldate.Text;
                    tableCelldate.BorderColor = "Grey";

                    tableRowday.Controls.Add(tableCelldate);
                    int pds = 0;

                    for (int j = 1; j <= period; j++)
                    {
                        HtmlTableCell tableCells = new HtmlTableCell();

                        string datet = lbldate.Text;

                        string[] p22 = { "flag", "ttid", "campusid" };
                        string[] v22 = { "3", ddlTimetable.SelectedValue, campusID.ToString() };
                        DataTable dtss = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", p22, v22);
                        if (dtss.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            DataTable ddt = new DataTable();


                            string[] pp = { "flag", "classid", "campusid" };
                            string[] vv = { "4", ddlclass.SelectedValue, campusID.ToString() };
                            ddt = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", pp, vv);
                            int count = 0;
                            if (ddt.Rows.Count > 0)//fill subjects
                            {
                                pds = pds + 1;
                                DateTime dat = Convert.ToDateTime(bl.SplitDate(datet));
                                DropDownList ddlsubjects = new DropDownList();
                                //ddlsubjects.CssClass = "dropdownMedium";

                                //ddlsubjects.Attributes.Add("style", "font-style:italic;color: #FF3399; font-size: 10px; border: thin groove #000000;width:300px");     
                                //ddlsubjects.Style = "color: #FF3399; font-size: 10px; border: thin groove #000000 ";
                                tableCells.BorderColor = "Grey";
                                //lbtnPeriodHead1.Text = "";
                                ddlsubjects.Font.Size = 8;
                                ddlsubjects.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray;
                                ddlsubjects.Height = Unit.Pixel(20);
                                tableCells.Controls.Add(ddlsubjects);
                                tableRowday.Controls.Add(tableCells);
                                // DropDownList ddlsubjects = (DropDownList)childItem.FindControl("ddlsubjects");
                                if (count < ddt.Rows.Count)
                                {
                                    string[] p5 = { "flag", "classid", "pdsno", "date", "campusid" };
                                    string[] v5 = { "1", ddlclass.SelectedValue, pds.ToString(), dat.ToString(), campusID.ToString() };
                                    DataTable dtb = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("[SP_timetablefinalsub]", p5, v5);
                                    if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        ddlsubjects.DataValueField = "SubjectClassid";
                                        ddlsubjects.DataTextField = "papername";
                                        ddlsubjects.DataSource = dtb;
                                        ddlsubjects.DataBind();
                                        ddlsubjects.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select One", "0"));
                                        count++;

                                        //fill datas in DB
                                        DateTime datt = dat;
                                        string[] p3 = { "flag", "ttid", "date", "campusid", "pdnum" };
                                        string[] v3 = { "6", ddlTimetable.SelectedValue, datt.ToString(), campusID.ToString(), pds.ToString() };
                                        DataTable d3 = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", p3, v3);
                                        if (d3.Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            if (d3.Rows[0][0].ToString()!= "0")
                                            {
                                                ddlsubjects.SelectedValue = d3.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                                            }   
                                        }
                                        //same group in any other class
                                        string[] p1 = { "flag", "classid", "fromdate", "todate" };
                                        string[] v1 = { "10", ddlclass.SelectedValue, bl.SplitDate(txtfrmdate.Text), bl.SplitDate(txttodate.Text) };
                                        DataTable dti = bl.SelectDataTableUsingSp("SP_timetablefinal", p1, v1);
                                        if (dti.Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            for (int s = 0; s < dti.Rows.Count; s++)
                                            {
                                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dti.Rows[s]["date"]) == dat)
                                                {
                                                    if (Convert.ToInt16(dti.Rows[s]["periodnum"]) == pds)
                                                    {
                                                        int sss = Convert.ToInt16(dti.Rows[s]["opgroupid"]);
                                                        ddlsubjects.SelectedValue = sss.ToString();
                                                        ddlsubjects.Enabled = false;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    tbltt.Controls.Add(tableRowday);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want a method to get the control **"ddlsubjects "** dynamically.that is i want to get its value .
Please give me an appropriate way to get this.Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign unique IDs to each control (ID property), you can use FindControl to get what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/486wc64h.aspx

FindControl finds by ID name regardles its nesting level, so:

```
<control id="name1">
  <control id="name1_1"></control>
  <control id="name1_2"></control>
  <control id="name1_3">
    <control id="name1_3_1">value</control>
  </control>
</control>
```

Look for "name1_3_1" with:

```
name1.FindControl("name1_3_1"); //Assuming they are all server-side controls, so runat="server" marked.
```

Will give you "name1_3_1", if present, null otherwise.